# Parse for attribute in xml namespace with element tree

Tags: xml, namespaces, elementtree, ovf

Using the following XML file, which is a vmware OVF:

```
<File ovf:href="foo.vmdk"/>
```

I need to change foo.vmdk to bar.vmdk

I used Element tree to parse through the file and he output showed me the namespace for each element

```
>>> for elem in tree.iter():
....   print elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text
{http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1}File {'{http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1}href': 'foo.vmdk'}
```

But if I try to parse for the tag File, it does not find it:

```
>>> for elem in tree.iterfind('File'):
...   print elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text
>>>
```

I understand that "http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" is the name space but how do I parse within that name space?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
>>> for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1}File'):
...   print elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text
>>>
```

(shameless plug: if you're wanting to work with OVFs in Python, take a look at [COT](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cot)...)